# can jquery svg fill html to the svg?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, raphael

i use this code   to fill **text** to svg using  raphaeljs:

```
var r = Raphael("holder", 200, 300);
var t = r.text(10, 10, "ssdwqdwq");
t.node.textContent='dddd'
```

raphaeljs **cant** fill html to svg  , can **jquery svg** or **svg web** do it  ?

thanks

Comment: Am I right in thinking you want to insert a HTML snippet within an SVG document?

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't worded very well, but it sounds/looks like you want to reset the text with something else. This can be done using the attributes of the text object using Raphael, and leads to this:

```
t.attr({text: "New String"});
```